# SSRS Page Design (8 pictures per Page)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Good day

The code below map a certain person from the "People" table to his/her picture in the "PeoplePicture" table and it is running very well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  People.person_id,
  People.ActivePassive,
  PeoplePicture.person_id,
  PeoplePicture.picture_id,
  PeoplePicture.Picture
  FROM People
  Right Join PeoplePicture
  On People.person_id = PeoplePicture.person_id
  WHERE People.ActivePassive = 'Active'
    And People.person_id In (@SelectePeople)​
```

Now I want to design a one page SSRS report so that I can display those pictures (max. 9 pictures per page or less) as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Please help me with the designing of the page.

Comment: Looks like you already have a design there. What are you *really* after here?

Comment: Whats your issue?

Comment: Looks like TS has no idea where to start from. I suggest Matrix report item with one cell to dynamically setup number of cells on both axis.

Comment: do I use a list? A rectangle? or ? Basically, what is my first step in SSRS?

Comment: Alex Peshik, can you please show me screen shoots please?

Comment: Yeah, i would say set up matrix which you can then add that code to

Comment: Just a sec, I'm creating such template with the code and report

Answer (score 1):

Please try this idea:

1. Add Matrix report item (not Rectangle nor List!), tune properties to show Border Style and Padding.
2. Add ColumnGroup and RowGroup columns to your dataset, they will be a basis for the Matrix.
3. Use Group columns on axis and Value inside (picture path, string description, values etc.)

Example:

```
;with 
Picture as
(select 1000 as ID union all
select 1001 as ID union all
select 1002 as ID union all
select 1003 as ID union all
select 1004 as ID union all
select 1005 as ID union all
select 1006 as ID union all
select 1007 as ID union all
select 1008 as ID union all
select 1009 as ID union all
select 10010 as ID union all
select 10011 as ID union all
select 10012 as ID union all
select 10013 as ID union all
select 10014 as ID union all
select 10015 as ID union all
select 10016 as ID union all
select 10017 as ID union all
select 10018 as ID union all
select 10019 as ID union all
select 10020 as ID)

,DatasetPreparation as
(select
 row_number() over (order by ID) as Row_ID
,(row_number() over (order by ID)-1)%3 as ColumnGroup_ID
,(row_number() over (order by ID)-1)/3 as RowGroup_ID
,*
from Picture)

select * from DatasetPreparation
```

This is simple random IDs that are going to be grouped by 3 columns.

[image: SSRS grouping]

Row_ID, RowGroup_ID, and ColumnGroup_ID are "system" columns for Matrix item.

Add these columns to Matrix this way:

[image: SSRS group Matrix]

Don't worry about SUM. We won't have intersections in Row/Column values (prepared this in dataset!). You can use First() or any other.

Final result is:
[image: SSRS group result]

This is a basic idea, you just need to tune it.

And use any value instead of 3 in ColumnGroup_ID and RowGroup_ID calculations to create several columns.